# Using mouseover to display information using flash actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash

I have a globe that rotates using a mousecontrol. But I want to display object information during mouseover to click the object.

below code : rotate by mouse

```
onEnterFrame = function(){


hero._rotation=getmouse(hero);

}

getmouse = function (mc:MovieClip):Number{


dy=_ymouse-mc._y;
dx=_xmouse-mc._x;
rad =Math.atan2(dy, dx);

rotate= rad*180/Math.PI;
return rotate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put your message on the image :) to be more stylistic.
Then you can set up the actionscript like this.
`image1_1_mc.onRollOver = function ()
{
     image1.alpha = 0;
     rolloverimage1.alpha = 100;`

having 20 of these images that you want to be able to rollover.

```
for (i=1; i<=20; i++) {
 ["image"+i+"_"+i+"_mc"].onRollOver = function () {
 ["image"+i].alpha = 0;
 ["rolloverimage"+i].alpha = 100;
 }
```

}

Comment: hi my image layer name is content, how i can declare image name. Plz could you help me.. thanks...

Comment: hi my movieclip property name is so. i used like this hero.onRollOver = function () { image1.alpha = 0; rolloverimage1.alpha = 100;  how i can display words like, when i mouseover the image i have to show globe rotating...